# 4x4 appwidgets are detected as 3x3 on tablets

Tags: android, tablet, android-appwidget

I create an 4x4 appwidget with minWidth and minHeight set to "250dp" as it is suggested in 
App Widget Design Guidelines:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

It is ok on every phones and phone-sized emulator I have tried but if I test it on a tablet (Xoom or Nexus 7) or on an emulator (resolution: 1280x752 with dpi 160)
then the launcher detects it as 3x3 widget.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Tamas

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `grid size = (74*n) - 2` for older api level. This value come from old document.