# Widget sizes in ICS

Tags: android, widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application with different sidget sizes, ie, 4x1, 4x2 and 5x2. The widget minWidgt and minHeight is,

4x1: 250dp x 40dp

4x2: 250dp x 110dp

5x2: 320dp x 110dp

Each widget uses a different layout in the widget-provider xml files.

On Gingerbread, when I try to add a widget on the home screen, the widgets appear correctly, ie, 4x1, 4x2 and 5x2. On ICS, they appear as 4x1, 4x2 and 4x2. Does anyone know why? The widget labels in the widget receiver definition (in the manifest file) are correctly defined as resource strings (widget_4x1, widget_4x2 etc).

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a change was made in the ICS source code, not allowing you to make the default size of your widget bigger than 4x4

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

**Note:** To make your app widget portable across devices, your app widget's minimum size should never be larger than 4 x 4 cells.

your widget has a size that is bigger than 4....

just let users re-size there widgets:

```
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

Comment: You are wrong to say that some code in ICS is not allowing your widget size to be bigger than 4x4. While 320dp should yield 5 tiles it does yield 4 sometimes. If you try a bigger number it still will give you 5 tiles width. The same as 250dp sometimes gives a size of 3 (especially on screens like the Nexus 7). (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868015/4x4-appwidgets-are-detected-as-3x3-on-tablets)