# AppWidget issue on tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

i designed an appwidget which should take up a width of 4 cells and a height of 1 cell.

Based on the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) this should be a 4x1 appwidget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="250dp"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="90000000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widgetlayout_2"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

**Notice:** `@layout/main` has width and height `match_parent`. It has nothing to do with the size of the `appwidget`, that is why i don't post the `XML-code` of `main`.

Everythink works fine on phones, maybe because you can't rotate them when on the homescreen.

But on tablet(tested with **Nexus 10 XHDPI 2560x1600 API16**) the `appWidget` is only measured with **3x1**!

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868015/4x4-appwidgets-are-detected-as-3x3-on-tablets) on stack with no answere. Maybe someone got an update.

The next issue is, that in landscape my design of the appwidget is as expected. But in Portrait, my `appWidget` got shrinked on the homescreen, the layout is messed up? Does somebody know how to prevent this, my only Approach would be to define a `layout-xlarge-port` Folder in my Project and put a customized layout for tablet in port mode in there?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: whats your desired cell dimensions? 4x1?

Comment: @waqaslam hey, i didn't specify them, i let the OS choose the absolute dp in width and height, i just want them to have 4x1 and that's why i declared `min-width` 250dp and `minHeight` 40dp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a **4x1** cells widget, you need to specify your **minWidth** and **minHeight** using the following formula:

> dpSize = (number of cells * 74) – 2

So mathematically, it should turned out to be:

```
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
```

These dimensions will set the default installation of your widget to **4x1** cells configuration. Installing your widget on tablets (which may have more than 4 horizontal cells) will also respect the same dimensions as shown in phones.

Regarding your second problem, you may define the following to restrict your widget's minimum re-sizeable width and height:

```
//for example this will set the minimum allowed re-size of 2x2 cells
android:minResizeWidth="146dp"
android:minResizeHeight="146dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

I think its a good idea to not to define your widget's cell distribution more than **4x4** cells as this division easily fits for phones and tablets and let the user to re-size. But in case you have a desire for a larger cell division for tablets then I would suggest you to define multiple `appwidget-provider` with custom cell configurations in folders respective to device screen densities. For example:

```
res
|-xml          //for ordinary screens, like phones and phablets
|-xml-w820dp   //for devices with minimum with of 820dp, like hi-res tablets and etc.
```

Comment: I got one question, when the minHeight is 72dp, why do i set the minResizeHeight to 146dp ? this doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't it be also 72dp? `Update` ah understand, i didn't read the line that this is an example for 2x2 cells. I will test it and give you Feedback. Thank you